# MCV6 EF Changing the sign of a decimal based on transaction type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, transactions

I'm storing transactions in an SQL database using EF code first and MVC6 I need to reverse the sign of the value based on the type of transaction. I want to do this at a central point so I don't have to make multiple changes throughout the app. i.e. on model creation or on the entity. Something like:

```
    public class Transactions : EntityBase
    {
        public TransactionType Type { get; set; }

        public decimal Amount
        {
            get
            {
                if (Type == Type.Refund && Amount > 0)
                    return Amount * -1;
                else
                    return Amount;
            }
            set { Amount = value; }
        }
    }
```

We could also store the value as a negative. Any suggestion on how best to achieve this?

Comment: Of course you can find a way to do this, but I would just store it correctly. This relies on the data being processed by EF to reflect the negative value of the transaction. If you generate a report using raw SQL or any other data access layer, your balance is going to be wrong without some similar handling.

Comment: That's fair, and we will need to store the value as a negative or hold a ValueType + or - to work with the Transaction Type. Logic will always be needed to display the correct total as users can post negative values for all transaction types I.e. £-50 Credit Note + £100 Credit Note + £100 Invoice = £50. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go ahead and create an unmapped property and one that is filled by EF.

```
    public class Transactions : EntityBase
    {
        public TransactionType Type { get; set; }
        public RawAmount { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public decimal Amount
        {
            get
            {
                if (Type == Type.Refund && RawAmount > 0)
                    return RawAmount * -1;
                else
                    return RawAmount;
            }
            set 
            { 
                Type = value > 0 ? Type.Expense : Type.Refund;
                Amount = Math.Abs(value); 
            }
        }
    }
```

If you are using fluent configurations in EF you could even make the *RawAmount* property protected, so it is not used by mistake.

Comment: This is good and we can use protected with [NotMapped] annotation, thank you.

Comment: Is there a way to create an expression where these properties will work in a LINQ to Entity query? We get an error using Amount as it convert to a SQL query. It works if request the unmapped properties after the query is called in memory.

Comment: @James the unmapped property works like any normal property as it is not directly handled by EF. To get it to work with an IQueryable you have to query over the mapped fields.